# WooCommerce Sequential Pro Number On Custom Invoice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, invoice

I have a custom plugin for Woocommerce developed that i need to amend to link with the sequential order number plugin.

```
$order = wc_get_order($_GET['returnid']);
```

Seems to get the order number and generates a returns form showing the order number in store. However since installing the sequential order number plugin the order numbers are out of sync.

Woocommerce documentation says to do this

```
$order_id = wc_seq_order_number_pro()->find_order_by_order_number( $order_number );
```

To get the order id but i have tried few things and nothing works.

Full plugin code is here https://codepen.io/foamymedia/pen/pQPZGw